# android memory card not showing in windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, android, sd-card, usb-storage

there is a small problem I have Windows 8.1 64 bit laptop when I connect my android phone recently the memory card does not show in my computer explorer window. Earlier it was showing. So upon googling I came across a few blogs where a common suggestion was to uninstall the USB driver for android memory card and reinstall it. When I reached on device manager I am not able to understand which
is the usb connection for my android phone memory card , that I should uninstall.
Here is a screenshot
[image]

Please suggest how to identify which device driver to uninstall and reinstall in the image.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the manufacturer. If your phone is made by Samsung or Huawei, it's one of those.

After you uninstall the driver, just plug the phone back in and your PC should automatically reinstall the driver.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes I did the same any how the memory card is not being detected in the phone also.

Comment: Hm. There may be an issue with the card. If you can remove it, and have an adapter, try to insert the card directly into the PC. Since two devices are having trouble seeing the card, that narrows down the possibilities.

Answer (score -1):

If the card does not detect inside the phone, nor in a PC/laptop (check if it appears in Disk Management in Windows with correct physical capacity) then most likely there is a problem with the card itself.

[image: check SD card in Disk Management]

No amount of reinstalling drivers will solve this and data recovery is beyond DIY I'm afraid. If the data is of no importance, replace the card.